# Ошибка в деструкторе сокета boost

Tags: c++, сокет, boost

Используется следующая модель абстракции:

```
//SHP_*** обозначены shared_ptr<***>
class A
{
    std::vector<SHP_B> vecB;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
}
class B
{
   B(...){socket = std::make_shared<Socket>(...);}
   ~B(){socket->s.close();}
   private: SHP_Socket socket;
}
class Socket
{
    Socket(...){s.open(...); s.set_option(...); s.bind(...);}
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket s;
}
```

Все эти классы и их реализация лежат в разных файлах.
Все прекрасно собирается, работает, инициализируется, сокеты шлют данные. В `vecB` добавляются и удаляются элементы... Пока не вызову деструктор класса `А`. При этом, в `vecB` должно содержаться (и содержится, проверил) `2` элемента `SHP_B`.

Тогда возникает ошибка доступа к памяти: `Unhandled exception at 0x77BE57DA (ntdll.dll) in Conference.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEF6.` и дебагер кидает в файл: `...\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp`

```
void win_iocp_socket_service_base::destroy(
    win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type& impl)
{
  close_for_destruction(impl);

  // Remove implementation from linked list of all implementations.
  boost::asio::detail::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
  if (impl_list_ == &impl) // <- дебагер указывает на эту строчку
    impl_list_ = impl.next_;
  if (impl.prev_)
    impl.prev_->next_ = impl.next_;
  if (impl.next_)
    impl.next_->prev_= impl.prev_;
  impl.next_ = 0;
  impl.prev_ = 0;
}
```

Я так понимаю, что ошибка вызвана попыткой удаления уже удаленного сокета или попыткой удаления открытого сокета(что вряд ли), но почему? Закрытие сокета я вызываю только в  `~B()`, который после исполнения должен вызвать и деструктор класса `Socket`, в котором вызывается деструктор для  `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket s`., пробовал закрывать вызовом вручную и удаление элементов из `vecB` по одному перед вызовом деструктора по умолчанию для класса `А` (ведь до того как мне надо удалить объект из `A` нормально работало...). Пробовал перенести закрытие сокета в `~Socket()` - не помогло.

Из-за чего возникла эта проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Попробуйте вынести `boost::asio::io_service io` из класса. Т.е. чтобы он жил и после уничтожения `A`.

Comment: @alexolut помогло. Спасибо! Но по логике нужно иметь для каждого объекта из `А` экземпляр `io_service` и отдельно их хранить не удобно. Поэтому благодаря Вашей наводке дописал в `~A()` очистку `vecB` перед автоматическим деструктором `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснилось в комментариях проблема в том, что объект типа `boost::asio::io_service` уничтожается раньше чем последний созданный на нем сокет.

Чтобы избежать этой ситуации можно создать пользовательский деструктор с правильным порядком очистки, что Вы и сделали. А можно просто поменять порядок членов:

```
class A
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    std::vector<SHP_B> vecB;
};
```

В таком случае, автоматически созданный деструктор будет сначала удалять `vecB`, а потом уже `io`. Правда в этом случае надо иметь в виду, что т.к. используется `shared_ptr` сокет может формально существовать ещё где-то. Если его существование в другим местах не предполагается - имеет смысл использовать другой тип умного указателя, например `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Автоматический деструктор идет с конца списка свойств класса? Если это так, то интересное и полезное знание)

Comment: @Dmitry члены-данные создаются в порядке объявления их в классе, а уничтожаются в обратном порядке. Так что можно сказать, что удаляются с конца, да.

Comment: Да, согласен, так тоже будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что ваш `io_service` уничтожается раньше, чем уничтожается сокет. Продлить время жизни можно двумя способами:

1. Вынести `io_service` наружу. Хорошим местом для создания `io_service` будет локальная переменная в функции `main` или в какой-нибудь подобной. Или вообще глобальная/статическая.
2. Создавать `io_service` через `shared_ptr`, сохраняя копию в каждом классе B.

Comment: В конструктор сокета мне же придется передавать `shp_io_service->get()`, разве в таком случае счетчик shared_ptr увеличится и будет ли он следить за этим экземпляром?

Comment: @Dmitry он увеличится, если вы будете хранить `shared_ptr` в классе B. Насколько я понимаю, главное - чтобы `io_service` жил в момент вызова `close` у сокета.

Comment: Не уверен можно ли после `close` сокет открыть снова, но если можно, то `io_service` по-прежнему должен жить. Т.е. лучше всё же убедиться что сокет уничтожен, а не просто закрыт.